# Циклический цикл

Tags: python, алгоритм

Язык не важен, поясню на примере языка питон:

```
myarray=['a', 'b', 'c']
number=3
def myfunc(myarray, number): #при number = 3
  newarray=[]
  for s1 in myarray
    for s2 in myarray
      for s3 in myarray
        newarray.append(s1+s2+s3)
  return newarray
```

должен возвратить: aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, итд, Т.е. если `number = 4`, то все четырехзначные, что можно составить, если 5, то пятизначные и тд.

Как это сделать?

Comment: почитайте про длинную арифметику, можно их здесь использовать. Т.е. ваши сочетания с повторениями можно рассматривать как постепенное увеличение на единицу (aaa + 1 = aab, abc + 1 = aca). Только надо будет учесть, что разрядность у вас ограничена числом number

Comment: Можно подробнее, что вы имели ввиду? Что увеличивать на единицу? ASCII код символа? Если да, то это не вариант, там не по порядку (некоторые символы могу быть пропущены, и не обязательно будут там буквы, могут и спецзнаки быть)

Comment: нет, увеличивать не ascii-код, а индекс в массиве myarray. Т.е. на каждом шаге у вас будет индекс следующего элемента равен `(index + 1) % 3` Вечером распишу алгоритм

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

chars = 'abc'

print(list(product(chars, repeat=3)))

# [('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ...
```

Выходные данные уже преобразуй во что нужно.

Вот псевдо-код реализации `product()` [из документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: Подозреваю, топикстартера интересует сам алгоритм, а не готовая функция из библиотеки.

Comment: @zed прав. Мне нужен алгоритм. В вопросе newarray и return для понимания вписал, а на деле все комбинации буду использоваться "на лету" (по мере генерирования). Держать в памяти дороговато будет, если это массив из 20 элементов на 20 повторений (т.е. 20 в 20 степени элементов).

Comment: @SamirRouth, понятно, вы, по факту, вычисляете элементы декартова произведения множеств, где множества это `n` списков `['a', 'b', 'c']`, никто вас хранить все в памяти не заставляет - используйте, например, генераторы (к слову itertools тоже вам не все скопом возвращает), посмотрите вот этот ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2419399/2787185

Comment: @SamirRouth, не надо ничего держать в памяти - `product` является итератором. Просто берите из него в цикле значения, да и всё. В этом ответе его обернули в print(list()) лишь для примера, что бы последовательность можно было вывести в консоль.

Comment: да, ступил, это же итератор!

Answer (score 2):

**Простой алгоритм генерации сочетаний с повторениями**: представим наше множество как набор цифр. Тогда все возможные сочетания с повторениями - это просто все возможные числа с заданной разрядностью на заданном наборе цифр.
Самый простой способ получить все возможные числа - выбрать некоторый "ноль" и постепенно его увеличивать.

Посмотрим как мы это делаем в арифметике. Допустим у нас есть цифры A, B и C и максимальная разрядность равна 2. За "ноль" примем первое число, т.е. A (а с учетом разрядности: AA)

Тогда, увеличивая это число на 1, мы сначала увеличиваем первый разряд на 1 (т.е. берем следующую возможную цифру), а если у нас возникает переполнение (т.е. больше нет доступных цифр), значит сбрасываем текущий разряд на "ноль" и увеличиваем следующий разряд числа на 1 и т.д.

Немного примеров:

```
ноль - AA
AA + 1 = AB (т.к. B - следующая цифра после A)
AB + 1 = AC (т.к. C - следующая цифра после B)
AC + 1 = BA (т.к. после C нет доступных цифр, то обнуляем первый разряд и увеличиваем на 1 второй разряд)
и т.д.
```

Т.е. ***алгоритм генерации наших сочетаний*** простой:

1. Генерируем первое число необходимой разрядности (ноль)
2. Увеличиваем число, полученное на предыдущем шаге на 1
3. Повторяем пункт 2 до тех пор, пока в последнем разряде не получим переполнение (т.е. следующее возможное число будет уже с разрядностью большей заданной)

***Алгоритм увеличения числа на 1*** тоже простой:

1. На входе у нас возможные цифры числа, само число и разряд, который мы собираемся увеличивать
2. Увеличиваем текущий разряд на 1
3. Если возникло переполнение - обнуляем текущий разряд и повторяем алгоритм для следующего разряда
4. Если возникло переполнение, но текущий разряд - последний в выбранной разрядности - мы получили максимальное число в выбранной разрядности

В коде на python это выглядит как-то так:

```
def increase_number(digits, number, increased_index = 0):
    number = list(number)
    total_digits_count = len(digits)
    number_digits_count = len(number)

    # было переполнение в последнем доступном разряде
    if increased_index >= number_digits_count:
        return False

    current_digit = number[increased_index]
    current_digit_index = digits.index(current_digit)

    # если в текущем разряде переполнение - увеличиваем на 1 следующий разряд
    if current_digit_index + 1 >= total_digits_count:
        number[increased_index] = digits[0]
        return increase_number(digits, number, increased_index + 1)

    # в текущий разряд пишем следующую по списку цифру
    number[increased_index] = digits[current_digit_index + 1]
    return number

def product(digits, repeat=3):
    all_products = []
    current_number = [digits[0]] * repeat
    while True:
        yield current_number
        current_number = increase_number(digits, current_number)

        # было переполнение последнего разряда, больше чисел нет
        if current_number == False:
            break

myarray=['5', 'O', 'S']
result = product(myarray, 2)
for number in result:
    print (''.join(number))

# Вывод:
# 55
# O5
# S5
# 5O
# OO
# SO
# 5S
# OS
# SS
```

Не стал заморачиваться, поэтому здесь числа немного перевернуты. Т.е. вместо числа 0123 на выводе будет 3210, но на результат это никоим образом не влияет

Comment: В комментарий не вошло ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не, почему же? вошло (см. [коммент к вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481744/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB/482100?noredirect=1#comment554736_481744)), вот только автор не понял что я хотел сказать, пришлось расписывать подробнее )

Answer (score 2):

Рекурсивный вызов

```
def myfunc(myarray, number=3):
    result=[]
    if number > 1:
        for s1 in myarray:
            tmp = myfunc(myarray, number - 1)
            for item in tmp:
                result.append(s1+item)
    else:
        result = myarray
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

[Только что](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480368/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-3d-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9/480511#480511) решал аналогичную проблему в теме про кластеризацию (процедура combinations), генерировал сочетания без повторений.

Адаптация труда не составляет (PHP):

```
function combi_all($chars, $num){
    $combi = [""];  
    for($n = 0; $n < $num; $n++){
        $combi_old = $combi;
        $combi = [];
        foreach($combi_old as $item){
            for($m = 0; $m < $num; $m++){
                $combi[] = $item.$chars[$m];
            }
        }
    }
    return $combi;
}

$combi = combi_all(["a","b","c","d"],3);
var_dump($combi);
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=27)
  0 => string 'aaa' (length=3)
  1 => string 'aab' (length=3)
  2 => string 'aac' (length=3)
  3 => string 'aba' (length=3)
  4 => string 'abb' (length=3)
  5 => string 'abc' (length=3)
  6 => string 'aca' (length=3)
  7 => string 'acb' (length=3)
  8 => string 'acc' (length=3)
  9 => string 'baa' (length=3)
  10 => string 'bab' (length=3)
  11 => string 'bac' (length=3)
  12 => string 'bba' (length=3)
  13 => string 'bbb' (length=3)
  14 => string 'bbc' (length=3)
  15 => string 'bca' (length=3)
  16 => string 'bcb' (length=3)
  17 => string 'bcc' (length=3)
  18 => string 'caa' (length=3)
  19 => string 'cab' (length=3)
  20 => string 'cac' (length=3)
  21 => string 'cba' (length=3)
  22 => string 'cbb' (length=3)
  23 => string 'cbc' (length=3)
  24 => string 'cca' (length=3)
  25 => string 'ccb' (length=3)
  26 => string 'ccc' (length=3)
```

Суть процедуры - в получении нового массива строк из старого путём дописывания буквы. Поскольку размерности массивов не совпадают, старый приходится переписывать.

Comment: ваш результат правильный для данного вопроса, но неверно называть это сочетанием без повторения (это совсем другое). Например, с точки зрения сочетаний `aab` и `aba` это одно и тоже. Ваша функция генерирует декартово произведение входной последовательности

Comment: @jfs Исходная программа генерировала сочетания, эта генерирует декартово произведение. Отличие на один индекс)